# Sum of positive values in an array gives negative result in a c program

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem that is, when I sum the values of an array (that are all positive, I verified by printing the values of the array), I end up with a negative value. My code for the sum is:

```
int summcp = 0;
for (k = 0; k < SIMUL; k++)
{
    summcp += mcp[k];
}
printf("summcp: %d.\n", summcp);`
```

Any hint about this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: In which dimensions do you calculate? Is an overflow possible? And what is the datatype of
    mcp?

Comment: If your sum exceeds the limit of integer it would then turn negative.Is this your case. Are the numbers very big>

Comment: Please show us the values of array `mcp` and `SIMUL`.

Comment: For debugging purposes, you might want to also print the value of summcp each time through the loop.  This smells like an overflow issue, and printing the sum as you go would confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking *undefined behaviour*.

As integer variables can only hold a limited range of values, going beyond this range is undefined by the standard. Basically anything can happen. In your (and the most common) case, it simply wraps around its binary representation. As this is used for negative values, you will read this as such.

To circomvent this, use a type for `summcp` which can hold *all* possible values. An alternative would be to check if the next addition will overflow by:

```
if ( summcp >= INT_MAX - mcp[k] ) {
    // handle positive overflow
}
```

Note that the above only works for `mcp[k] >= 0` and positive overflow. The other 3 cases have to be handled differently. It is in general best, faster and much easier to use a large enough type for the sum and test lateron for overflow, if required.

Do not feel tempted to add and test the result!. As integer overflow is *undefined behaviour*, this will not work for all architectures.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Indeed, I was using int when I had a huge number after the sum. So, I changed the type to long and now I have a positive meaningfull value.

Comment: Just make sure the new type can represent at least `SIMUL * -INT_MIN` (!) values.

Answer (score 2):

This smells like an overflow issue; you might want to add a check against that like

```
for (k = 0; k < SIMUL && (INT_MAX - summcp > mcp[k]); k++ )
{
  sumcp += mcp[k];
}

if (k < SIMUL)
{
  // sum of all mcp values is larger than what an int can represent
}
else
{
  // use summcp
}
```

If you are running into overflow issues, you might want to use a wider type for `summcp` like `long` or `long long`.

**EDIT**

The problem is that the behavior of signed integer overflow is not well-defined; you'll get a different result for `INT_MAX + 1` based on whether your platform uses one's complement, two's complement, sign magnitude, or some other representation for signed integers.

Like I said in my comment below, if `mcp` can contain negative values, you should add a check for underflow as well.

Regardless of the type you use (`int`, `long`, `long long`), you should keep the over- and underflow checks.

If `mcp` only ever contains non-negative values, then consider using an unsigned type for your sum.  The advantage of this is that the behavior of *unsigned* integer overflow is well-defined, and the result will be the sum of all elements of `mcp` modulo `UINT_MAX` (or `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX`, etc.).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Indeed, I was using int when I had a huge number after the sum. So, I changed the type to long and now I have a positive meaningfull value.

Comment: @RuiJoãoLoureiro: That's great, but you should probably keep the overflow check (substitute `LONG_MAX` for `INT_MAX`), unless you *know* the sum of all elements in `mcp` won't ever exceed `LONG_MAX`.  Also, can the sum ever wind up being negative (i.e., every element of `mcp` is negative)?  If so, then you should add an underflow check as well.

Answer (score 1):

Declare variable `summcp` like

```
long long int summcp = 0;
```

Comment: That might be sufficient, or it might not — and it doesn't explain why there's a problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Indeed, I was using int when I had a huge number after the sum. So, I changed the type to long and now I have a positive meaningfull value.

Answer (score 1):

I think your final output is going out of range. For this you will have to declare `summcp` as `long long int`

```
long long int summcp = 0;
for (k = 0; k < SIMUL; k++)
{
    summcp += mcp[k];
}
printf("summcp: %lld.\n", summcp);
```

`int` variable throws garbage value if its range is exceeded.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Indeed, I was using int when I had a huge number after the sum. So, I changed the type to long and now I have a positive meaningfull value.